# Strange jQuery Animation Behavior - Keeps Running Over and Over

Tags: css, jquery-animate

**The Issue**
I'm animating some text in from left to right. It should only run once and be done when it's in view (should not run until it's in view!), but for some reason, while it's correctly waiting for it to be in view, this is looping over and over, slowly pushing the element off the page.

If you have any insight for me regarding how to stop this oddity, I would greatly appreciate it!

Here's an example of the website where this can be seen as well if find it useful.

https://stable.stable-demos.com/who-we-are/

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
      x = $('.div6').offset().top - 100;
      if (y > x) {
         $('.div6').delay(1300).animate({ opacity: 1, "margin-left": '+=50'});
      } else {
        // do not run the animation
      }
  });
 });
```

```css
.div6 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div6">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h2>At The Stable, we are for you. We tackle your problems for you and celebrate your victories with you.</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a track of whether the animation has been triggered, and not let it fire after that. It can be done through a variable as shown below:

```js
var done = false;
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!done) {
      var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
        x = $('.div6').offset().top - 100;
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div6')
          .delay(1300)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.div6 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div6">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>At The Stable, we are for you. We tackle your problems for you and celebrate your victories with you.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much. I hadn't even considered that (novice here!). I really appreciate your help :D

Comment: No biggie, glad to help!

Comment: Done! If you have a moment, could I ask you a question? I actually have multiple paragraphs that should load with varying delays based on when that div comes into view. Do I need to create a bunch of scroll functions for each of those (8 different divs that should animate when they are in view), or should I be adding some kind of additional if statements inside the one scroll function?  (You can kind of see what I mean at the link to the site above. Thank you again!

Comment: You can create an array of `done` variables like so: `doneArr = [ { el: '#div2', done: false }, {..similar for other divs..} ]` Then in the same function as above, you can loop through this array, check for offset of each `div`, and set corresponding `done` to `true`.

Comment: I have issues in a click event that has to show/hide stuff. Gotta figure out how to do that without issues since it isn't just one and done like this.